# Dataset conversion to Linq object

Tags: performance, wcf, linq-to-sql, dataset

Our WCF services return Datasets to the webserver,

In the new .NET web site we are going to use MVC 5. Since MVC 5 framework works really well with known business objets (validation framework etc.), we need to convert Datasets to known business objects in the Model classes.

We tried following conversion,

```
public List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        List<Category> cats = new List<Category>();

            DataTable dt = //get data table from the dataset;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Category cat = new Category();
                cat.CategoryID = int.Parse(row["CategoryID"].ToString());
                cat.CategoryName = row["CategoryName"].ToString();
                cat.Description = row["Description"].ToString();
                cat.Picture = GetBytes(row["Picture"].ToString());
                cats.Add(cat);
            }

        return cats;
    }
```

Assume that we retrieve and unpack the data table.
Will this be an expensive conversion if there are 100s' of request per second accessing this code block? 
What would be a better way to test the performance under load?
Or is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about the time it takes to convert the DataSet to domain objects since it's going to be a fraction of the remote call to get the data through a remote service. 
However, for result sets that rarely change I would recommend adding caching around the resolved domain objects to avoid the conversion, but more importantly avoid the WCF call and subsequent DB call.